# Getting 401 (access denied) when trying to use the REST API

Tags: rest-api

I have a WordPress site in wordpress.com with the Business plan which enables the REST API. I can test the API by listing blog posts doing a GET request to `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`, but POST request to create or modify a post all return a 401. For example:

```
$ curl --user "flexpointtechunbreach:{application_password}" -X POST -d "title=New Title" https://testbed.flexpoint.tech/wp-json/wp/v2/posts
{"code":"rest_cannot_create","message":"Sorry, you are not allowed to create posts as this user.","data":{"status":401}}

$ curl --user "flexpointtechunbreach:{application_password}" -X POST -d "title=New Title" https://testbed.flexpoint.tech/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/8
{"code":"rest_cannot_edit","message":"Sorry, you are not allowed to edit this post.","data":{"status":401}}
```

`flexpointtechunbreach` is a user that I created and added to the site with Editor role:

[image]

I triple checked the application password was correct, generated a new one just in case and tried that.

[That post, id 8](https://testbed.flexpoint.tech/2022/07/23/testing/), was created by the user `flexpointtechunbreach`:

[image]

I asked customer support at wordpress.com and they told me everything seems to be set up correctly on the WordPress site.

I'm writing a program that will interact with the API. Over there I tried many different parameters, added `app_name`, `app_id`, right or wrong credentials and nothing worked.

Any ideas what else it could be?

Comment: It looks like it's accepting your credentials but failing a permission check for the post specifically. The check is here: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/6.0.1/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-posts-controller.php#L1642 It just checks if this post type is flagged show_in_rest - is this a custom post type? - and that the user has permission to edit it.

Comment: For the first one, it looks like you're setting the request author to some other users's ID. Can you set it to that users's ID? [relevant code here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/6.0.1/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-posts-controller.php#L589-L595)

Comment: @Rup: it's not a custom post, I just created it with the same user in the web UI of an otherwise pristine wordpress.com instance. I don't know what `show_in_rest` is. Anything I should check?

Comment: @Rup: how do I set the request author? I'm not sure I follow what you mean here. The user is specified in the curl line. I haven't specified a user id anywhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. WordPress.com has two different application passwords. The one in the 2FA set up page is the wrong one and that's the one I was setting up. To set the right one you need to go to /wp-admin/profile.php. Once I did that, this code started working.

I wrote a blog post with lots of details about all the moving parts in case you want more details: https://pablofernandez.tech/2022/07/31/creating-blog-posts-in-wordpress-com-programatically/

Comment: I tried going to /profile.php and it just shows an empty page saying "Were you looking for your API Key and other Personal Settings?". Going to there doesn't show the application password stuff either